# Volume Fn keys get "stuck down" in Kubuntu and Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, 15.10, volume-control, function-keys

I've had a dual boot with Ubuntu for a while. One problem annoyed me though, that my Volume Fn keys got "stuck down" whenever I pressed them, making it max volume, or muted. This has happened every time I tried in every application, and I even gave a triple boot to the laptop with Kubuntu, where the problem persists there as well. I also checked possible duplicates, but they said it was occasionally, and not always. Any help?